# Matrix multiplication of more than two matrices.

Tags: matrices

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Can we perform Matrix multiplication of more than two matrices?

Example : A.B.C where A,B,C are three matrices.

Can we generalize for multiplication of n number of matrices?

Comment: Yes, the sizes have to match up. But otherwise, no problem. For square matrices, it's like for numbers of a field. If you can multiply two of them, then also three and so on. Of course, matrix multiplication is not commutative in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix multiplication is, by definition, a *binary operation*, meaning it is only defined on two matrices at a time.  That said, so long as the dimensions are compatible, you can multiply more than two matrices together by iterating the multiplication two at a time.  For example, if you have $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, and $C \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ then you could form the product $ABC$ because regardless of which adjacent pair you multiplied first the dimension of the resulting product would allow for multiplication with the third.

Comment: Thanks. Can we generalise a formula or equation to compute multiplication for n number of matrices?

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar:  certainly.  Using the repeated index convention, if $ABC=D$ we have $D_{ij}=A_{ik}B_{km}C_{mj}$